# Cancelling values in sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, contest-math, divergent-series

*Question: Find the sum of all integer values of c such that $x^2 +cx+\frac{1}{4}c$ has two real, distinct roots.*

The discriminant must be greater than zero for a quadratic to have two real, distinct, roots:
$$ c^2-(4)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)c>0\implies c(c-1)>0\implies c \in (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$$

And now we want the sum:
$$...-3-2-1+2+3+4+...$$

Note that we can make pairs $-2+2=0, -3+3=0$ except for $-1$, which is unpaired, and the hence the final answer is
$$-1$$

Is the above logic correct? Particularly the part where the infinite series is summed? Is there a flaw in the question?

Comment: The summation is not well-defined. The order in which you sum these terms will lead to different values. For example, you can sum it in the following way as well: $-1+(2+3)-2+(4+5)-3+(6+7)-4+...$ and get a sum of $\infty$.

Comment: Also, your intervals should include $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck: the problem asks for **distinct** roots

Comment: @GCab The original question did not ask for distinct roots.

Comment: I see, alas it is a usual bad habit to change the text fundamentally after the publication